# Is there any way to check if a given string exists in any array element?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Suppose a given string exists, `s="abc"`
Is there any way to check if that given string exists in an array, such as,

```
arr=["pnq","dwksnn","inabcpi","poals"]
```

Any method/way to see so that a condition will return true in such a case?

Comment: Do you mean it needs to match the whole string or do you want to search within each string to see if it's there?

Comment: @Andy I want to search over each of the array elements and see if the the array element contains the given string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple, you need to iterate over the given array and check if this string exists in each of the strings within the array.

```
const arr = ['pnq', 'dwksnn', 'inabcpi', 'poals'];
const stringToFind = 'abc';
const doesStringExist = arr.find(item => item.includes(stringToFind));

// OR if you don't want to know which string the given string is a part of, you could use `Array.prototype.some`

const doesStringExist = arr.some(item => item.includes(stringToFind));

console.log(`The string ${stringToFind} ${doesStringExist ? 'Exists' : 'Doesn\'t Exist'}`);
```

Comment: Maybe [`.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) would be more appropriate instead of `.find()` here, as `.some()` will return a boolean which is what you're after :)

Comment: I agree.. Updating the answer

Answer (score 1):

you need to search over each array element and check if the given string is contained within any of the elements, you can use the `some()` method. Here's the JavaScript code:

```
const s = "abc";
const arr = ["pnq", "dwksnn", "inabcpi", "poals"];

const is_exists = arr.some(element => element.includes(s));
console.log(is_exists); // true if exists, otherwise false
```

Comment: Based on the title of the question, OP wants to check if the string is contained within one of the array elements, not if the string is in the array as a whole element. OPs example should return true as they've mentioned.

Comment: No, I want the answer as in how @NickParsons said it

Comment: Apologies for the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the array method [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some), and the string method [`includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes).

```js
const arr = ['pnq', 'dwksnn', 'inabcpi', 'poals'];

// Return true if the array has an element that
// includes the query string, otherwise false
function finder(arr, query) {
  return arr.some(el => el.includes(query));
}

console.log(finder(arr, 'abc'));
console.log(finder(arr, 'abcd'));
console.log(finder(arr, '123'));
console.log(finder(arr, 'pnq'));
console.log(finder(arr, 'oal'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this? using the `.includes()`?

```
const arr=["pnq","dwksnn","inabcpi","poals"]
function check_presence(elem) {
    return arr.includes(elem)
}
console.log(check_presence("pnh"))
```

Comment: Sorry, but .includes doesn't return true if only part of the array matches the string.

Comment: oh ok, my bad, I misinterpreted the question sorry. 
But `.includes()` can be used anyway. Check @Andy response

Answer (score 0):

we can use the includes() method to check.

```
var arr=["pnq","dwksnn","inabcpi","poals"];

console.log(arr.indexOf("pnq") > -1)
```